# Maximum number of databases that can be created per logical server on Azure

Tags: azure-sql-database

What is the maximum number of databases that we can create in a single Azure logical server?

Comment: Take a look at azure  docs?

Answer (score 4):

*There is soft limit of 150 databases per server.*

However customers can get that limit removed by calling the Azure Help Desk and going through a credit check process.

Contact azure support for precise response [here](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/contact/)